# Nuitka and numpy-mkl problem, while building executable

Tags: python, numpy, executable, intel-mkl, nuitka

I want to create executable of my program. I have installed nuitka and simply wrote in command prompt `Nuitka My_Program.py` . So, I got my executable created.When I write in command prompt `My_Program.exe` it successfully runs. On the other side, when I want to run it by clicking on it, I have this error:

```
numpy\__init__.py:140: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
```

How I can improve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these websites, and see if it helps you.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15590

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Can-not-run-Python-script-in-powerbi-desktop/m-p/1340532#M577363